# "cuDNN not available" in virtualenv

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, theano

I'd like to use cuDNN in a Theano project. I'm on Ubuntu where I have no sudo privileges and am using virtualenv.

The environment variableis set to the absolute path of where cuDNN is stored:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ME/cudnn:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

but I still get the error `cuDNN not available`. The program is running on the GPU anyways, so there is no issue with CUDA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Update ldd by running `sudo ldconfig`. You need to run this command after changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib). The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.

Comment: I don't have sudo privileges. Is there any way around this?